# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\Classic .NET AppPool'

Tags: asp.net, iis

I just added my website to IIS. After much troubleshooting I was able to make it run with the Classic .NET App Pool.

But on the page which requires connecting with the database, I am getting the error "Login failed for the user 'IIS APPPOOL\Class .NET AppPool'

Please suggest a workaround.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Are you using integrated security in the DB connection string? if so, you either need to change the connection string to specify a username or password. or change the asp.net settings in IIS to enable impersonation, this will mean the web app is running as another specified user (you would need to ensure the alternate user has access to the database otherwise you will have the same problem!)

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had another small problem. Earlier I had an index.html that displayed on typing http://localhost:9020/ I replaced that with an index.aspx but that is not displayed as home page. Direcorty browsing in IIS is off

Comment: Hi Cipher - sorry for the delay. Have you checked to see if index.aspx is set as a default document in IIS? its in IIS > HTTP Features > Default Document. You would need to add index.aspx in here for it to pick it up automatically. N

Answer (score 0):

- Go into IIS Manager
- On the node with your computer name, select "Application Pools"
- Click "Classic .NET AppPool" and select "Advanced Settings..."
- Select "Identity" property and change its value to "LocalSystem"

Comment: LocalSystem should not be used: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(WS.10).aspx